# Menu icons dropping off

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

I'm currently having an issue with the menu bar, it will work 75% of the time, but after a while it will start to drop off the Shown items and won't add them or any others back onto the visible items (It will still add to the hidden items)

This is what its meant to look like

(Main Screen)

[image]

(ViewPager Fragment

[image])

And it looks fine most of the time, but after a while the visible items drop off and don't come back (When moving between fragment on the viewPager i clear and inflate the menu, but i've removed this and the issue still occurs)

(Main Screen)

[image]

(ViewPager Fragment)
[image]

The items inside the Elapsed icon at the end all generate fine and get added as they're meant to, its just the ones that're meant to be visible that aren't showing

This is the ViewPager onCreateOptionsMenu function

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    // Clear Sync and Settings menu
    menu.clear()

    // Inflate the options menu from ViewModel
    inflater.inflate(viewModel?.getMenuLayout() ?: R.menu.job_details_menu, menu)

    // Let the VM handle the creation
    viewModel?.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

I have tried placing the super call at the start and end, it hasn't made a difference.

This is the Main Menu function

```
  @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu,@NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

    // Add the Schedule Search
    final MenuItem item = menu.add(App.getAppContext().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    sv.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
            if (!queryTextFocused) {
                item.collapseActionView();
            }
        }
    });
    item.setActionView(sv);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Why would this be not refreshing correctly? (Mostly the ViewPager Fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

To

```
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: The items aren't being hidden in the Elapsed menu, they're not on the menu completely, plus this needs to be compatible with tablets and mobiles, so i can't force them out if they won't fit

Comment: I did try this solution anyways to see if it would work, but sadly not

Comment: Ok, try to add them as image buttons or image views to your custom toolbars instead, and add the dropdown ones as you do usually.